# Unity huge iOS build size

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, size

I'm making a kids app for *Android* and *iOS*. And I did release build of both platforms.

**Android**
 - Download size(apk size): about 50MB
 - Installed size: about 75MB

**iOS** (on itunes connect)
 - Donwload size: about 68MB
 - Install size: about 245MB

Why is *iOS* release build so huge than *Android*? I've been googling to find the answer, and found that this issue is prevalent for other developers. I referenced the links below. (My reputation point is insufficient for more 2 links)

https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1165084/huge-ios-build.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1199032/huge-ios-build-size.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/462972/iphone-build-game-size-is-too-big.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1003162/why-is-ios-install-size-so-much-larger-than-androi.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357667/why-is-my-ios-app-size-an-order-of-magnitude-large.html

And so on.. and at result, I did like below.

1. **Release** build (not development build)
2. **POT** and almost **RGBA compressed PVRTC 4 bits**
3. Disable checkboxes ‘**include bitcode …**’ and ‘**include app symbol…**’
4. Architecture: ‘**Universal**’
5. Script Call Optimization: ‘**Fast but no Exception**’

And my *Editor.log*

**Android**

```
Textures      267.0 mb   81.3% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    4.6 mb     1.4% 
Sounds        14.1 mb    4.3% 
Shaders       286.4 kb   0.1% 
Other Assets  6.4 mb     1.9% 
Levels        29.7 mb    9.0% 
Scripts       872.2 kb   0.3% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     1.2% 
File headers  1.5 mb     0.5% 
Complete size 328.4 mb   100.0%
```

**iOS**

```
Textures      150.6 mb   71.1% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    4.6 mb     2.2% 
Sounds        14.1 mb    6.6% 
Shaders       175.7 kb   0.1% 
Other Assets  6.4 mb     3.0% 
Levels        29.7 mb    14.0% 
Scripts       865.7 kb   0.4% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     1.9% 
File headers  1.5 mb     0.7% 
Complete size 211.9 mb   100.0%
```

Weirdly, complete size of android is larger than *iOS*'. What's the problem? And How can I solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity iOS App Size weighs 1.2GB (real size) (Android 100MB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613864/unity-ios-app-size-weighs-1-2gb-real-size-android-100mb)

Comment: @JeanLuc I used RGBA Compressed PVRTC 4bits, neither True Color and 16bits. My textures has transparency, but it is not the problem for build size but image quality according to the link.

Comment: could it be that you are using "RGBA ETC2 8bits" on Android instead of "RGBA PVRTC 4bits"? PVRTC on Android does not make much sense, see also the recommendations in section [ETC as recommended texture compression](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html)

Comment: @JeanLuc RGB + 1 bit Alpha Compressed ETC2 4 bits for Android and RGBA compressed PVRTC 4 bits for iOS. My problem is huge iOS build size. The installed size of Android build is appropriate.

Comment: if you unzip your APK, how big does it get compared to the iOS install size?