# Real size limitations for iOS - "app exceeds 100mb download limit?"

Tags: ios

Ok, Ive looked around on all Apple's forums but Ive found some discrepancies in the max file size allowed for iOS apps. This is critical as I need to drastically reduce file size if this is a problem -

I read that the max uncompressed size for iOS is 4gb, however in iTunes connect I am getting a warning next to my compressed size 110mb size:
[image]
[image]

First I don't understand whether this limit refers to the compressed or uncompressed install size - Apple was no help. Ive looked at [Unity iOS App Size weighs 1.2GB (real size) (Android 100MB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613864/unity-ios-app-size-weighs-1-2gb-real-size-android-100mb) and others built with Unity but they have different issues -

Apple said that this 100mb limit is for over cellular downloads and won't stop your app from going on the App store. Is this true? What is compressed size limit for iOS apps and how does one "thin" an app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 100 Mb is size of produced .ipa file (which is a zip file).
You can put your heavy resources, such as video, audio and images to some web backend and later download them on first launch and store locally.

Other way is to try to optimize/convert resources, for example use JPEG instead of PNG, m4a instead of wav and so on.